# How can I prevent glossy areas when using chalkboard paint?

Tags: painting, paint, repainting

We recently tried to make a chalkboard wall with not-great results, and I was wondering if anyone has any tips.

First I sanded down the existing latex paint to get rid of some of the texture, then applied two coats (first with a low nap roller, second with a foam roller when the first coat didn't look great). Used this stuff: https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/specialty/chalkboard-brush-on/

The roller marks are still very evident, and various parts of the wall appear to be matte, while others are glossy. I've painted a LOT of walls, and have never had this problem. Most other latex paints I've used seem thicker than this, and end up just drying much more evenly.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hey Teddy, if you could add an image of the result (that you're not happy with), that might be helpful. Also, do you know what you painted _over_ with the chalkboard paint?

Comment: @isherwood: Newish home. Just sanded down the existing latex paint to get rid of as much texture as I could. Painted over that.